# what does the phrase “have sense enough” mean?

Tags: grammar

Does "have sense enough" mean "have enough sense"?

> I don't have sense enough to come in out of the pain.

Comment: I think you meant "in out of the **rain**" You need to say what research you have done, where you have seen this phrase. Why you think it might not be correct? Please add some details, don't wait until someone posts an answer and then fill the comment section with more questions and challenges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting expression. The phrase "I don't have sense enough to come in out of the pain" is the name of a song by George Jones. It is a creative modification of the common expression "not know enough to come in out of the rain". It is basic common sense to go inside when it's raining to avoid getting wet, so the phrase means "not have common sense", and the writer extends the phrase to mean that he hasn't enough sense to avoid the pain of his rocky love affair.

Your question was about the order of the words "have sense enough to X", compared to "have enough sense to X". They mean exactly the same thing. An ngram comparison shows that "sense enough" used to be much more common:
[Ngram "sense enough, enough sense"](https://tinyurl.com/y7wm3jlo)